# Can we find a curve that covers the unit sphere s.t any point $x$ on the unit sphere $S^2$, the curve passes through $x$ at least once?

Tags: manifolds, surfaces, curves

Can we find a curve such that it covers the unit sphere in a way that given any point $x$ on the unit sphere $S^2$, the curve passes through $x$ at least once ?

Comment: Transport this somehow to the sphere:   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_curve

Comment: You can have a Peano curve cover an $n$-**ball** if you like.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier is there a way to write down curve analytically for n-ball ?

Comment: Not that I ever heard of. In practice, these curves are defined as limits of piecewise defined curves. Most explicit examples are nowhere differentiable.

Comment: Look this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1748337/sphere-filling-curve