# Are there known "native" sphere filling curves?

Tags: curves, spherical-geometry

I am researching some applications of space filling curves in geospatial computation.

I'm familiar with the concept of space-filling curves as they apply to Euclidean spaces.

Currently major geospatial libraries (such as [S2](https://s2geometry.io/)) map Euclidean space filling curves (such as the [Hilbert curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_curve)) to a sphere for purposes of creating a spatial mapping from 1 dimension to all points on a sphere.

I'm making this post to ask if there are any known "native" sphere filling curves that are not constructed by [mapping one or more Euclidean curves to a sphere](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1748337/sphere-filling-curve) but rather natively constructed using [spherical geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_geometry).

I'm particularly interested in curves that preserve locality like the Hilbert curve does (i.e. not a spiral).

Comment: A variant on this is to fill a disk rather than a square. Some examples are shown [here](http://squircular.blogspot.com/2016/01/hilbert-curve-on-circular-disk.html) but I'm not sure any of them feel intrinsically "circular".

Comment: There isn't such a thing as "native" vs "non-native" curves. Mapping from a square is just a convenience in defining the curve. The result is still a curve on the sphere. What is it you are trying to get from "native" curves? You talk about "preserving locality", but it isn't clear what you mean. All curves are continuous (it's part of the definition). But in no space-filling curve - not even Hilbert's - are the pre-images for every point tightly clustered.

Comment: Is [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3s7h2MHQtxc) what you are referring to as "locality"? If so, then every space filling curve defined as a limit of non-space-filling curves will have this property. It is a necessity of the definition. In particular, if $(\theta, \phi)$ are spherical coordinates, and $h(t) = (h_1(t), h_2(t))$ is the Hilbert curve, then $$\theta(t) = 2\pi h_1(t)\\\phi(t) = \pi h_2(t) - \frac{\pi}2$$ is a space-filling curve on the sphere, which is a limit of the corresponding transformations of the "psuedo-Hilbert curves" that converge to $h$.

Comment: Yes, I'm referring to locality in the same sense as that video.

I'm specifically investigating "native" curves (curves constructed without mapping a Euclidean curve) as a potential way around the computational cost of the projection/transformation involved in mapping an approximation of a Euclidean space-filling curve to a sphere.